# Override the view column of a dropdownlist (MVC3, Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

When I use the auto creation of controllers/models/views from entity framework and designer I get a pretty clean edit form.  One of the 1 to 1 relationships creates a dropdownlist that presents the user with values from a specific column but I want it to user another column/property.

How is this done?

(FYI, I'm not looking for a class in MVVM and how to isolate this in a view model.  I don't have the bandwidth to learn and recreate this application with view model classes.)

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Domain, "Domain1")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("Domain", String.Empty))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Domain)
    </div>
```

controller:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        ClientJob clientjob = db.ClientJobs.Find(id);
        ViewBag.ClientId = new SelectList(db.Clients, "Id", "ClientName", clientjob.ClientId);
        ViewBag.CurrencyType = new SelectList(db.CurrencyTypes, "Id", "TypeName", clientjob.CurrencyType);
        ViewBag.Domain = new SelectList(db.Domains, "Id", "DomainName", clientjob.Domain);
        ViewBag.JobType = new SelectList(db.JobTypes, "Id", "JobTypeName", clientjob.JobType);
        ViewBag.DatabaseServer = new SelectList(db.Servers, "Id", "ServerName", clientjob.DatabaseServer);
        ViewBag.ProcessingServer = new SelectList(db.Servers, "Id", "ServerName", clientjob.ProcessingServer);
        ViewBag.QueryServer = new SelectList(db.Servers, "Id", "ServerName", clientjob.QueryServer);
        return View(clientjob);
    }
```

Comment: I think I just answered my own question... LOL

Comment: see my latest comment on my answer or my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The auto created code just created select lists:

```
ViewBag.Domain = new SelectList(db.Domains, "Id", "DomainName", clientjob.Domain);
```

I just needed to change the column name in the SelectList:

```
ViewBag.Domain = new SelectList(db.Domains, "Id", "DomainType", clientjob.Domain);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you want to pass a list of items to show instead of the default?

I do it like this:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Domain, "Domain1")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListfor(model => model.Domain, ViewData["DomainSelects"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Select domain")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Domain)
</div>
```

And then in your controller, be sure to set the `DomainSelects` in the view data.
The value property of the SelectListItem is the value that should be set for "domain". So if it is an FK it would be an id.

I use code like this (pseudo code)

```
ViewData["DomainSelects"] = domains.Select(domain => new SelectListItem() { Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)domain.Id), Text = domain.Name});
```

Comment: Did you apply the "ToString" when creating the SelectListItem? On what line do you get the error?

Comment: the view shows the error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Please post the exact code you use. I've been using this at the latest earlier today. Though not with Linq To Entities, only Linq To Sql. Should work anyhow though

Comment: @Chris Try to replace domain.Id.ToString() with SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)domain.Id)

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, prepare the whole list

```
ViewBag.YourTypeCollection = context.YourTypes.ToList();
```

And in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Domain, 
     new SelectList((IEnumerable<YourType>)ViewBag.YourTypeCollection,
     "Id",
     "Name",
     Model.Domain==null?1:Model.Domain.Id))
```

Id is the classes id field and Name is the field you want to show. Replace those with values appropriate for your model. In my example if the model's value is null, I select the first item.